# Configure URL depending on environment

Tags: c#, azure

I have published a website (MVC frontend) and an API, that is hosted on Azure on two different domains. The MVC frontend calls the API (through url), but right now, I manually switch the url manually between when I work locally, and when I deploy it:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://myApiDomain.azurewebsites.net"); //https://localhost:44393/ 
                                                                   /* I set one URL as 
                                                                    baseaddress and keep 
                                                                    the other in a comment,
                                                                    depending on environment */
```

Right now it is set to the hosted API address, myApiDomain. So if I work locally, I exchange the two addresses. And when I deploy, I put back in the azurewebsites-url.

Also, I would prefer not committing the URL directly to the source-code, but maybe a config file or similar instead - preferably one that is commonly ignored by git, so that it will not be displayed if its open source-code.

What is the smarter way to do this?

Comment: Put it into config. Look around in ````System.Configuration```` namespace for builtin things.

Comment: @cly Thanks for the pointer, will give `System.Configuration` a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different codes to be compiled for local work or testing and deployment, you can use the predefined DEBUG macro. Example:

```
using System;

namespace debugorrelease
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
#if DEBUG
            Console.WriteLine( "I am in debug mode, which is used for development." );
#else
            Console.WriteLine( "I am in release mode, which is used for deployment." );
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

You can set if you are in debug or release mode near the top menu in visual studio.

[image: debug / release combobox]

Comment: Thanks for the information, wasn't aware of this option. Appreciate it!